# how to show react bootstrap modal inside the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react bootstrap modal popup. when user submit form, I need to modal show popup,

This is my modal (SaveConfirmationModal )

```
    import { Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
function SaveConfirmationModal(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal {...props} size="lg">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            do u want to save ?
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <button>YEs </button>
          <button>No</button>
        </Modal.Body>
       
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SaveConfirmationModal;
```

this is my invoice page save function. I imported my modal in to the invoice page.

```
import SaveConfirmationModal from "components/createinvoice/SaveConfirmationModal";
 const loadPopup= (data) => {
  showmodal;
  if(yes){
    saveForm();
    }
else{
close modal
}
}

const saveForm= (data){
 my save function
}
```

my save button in the invoice page

```
<button onClick={loadPopup}> Save </button>
```

This is the very little sample to demonstrate my issue. If you can please help me to show this confirmation box. thanks

Comment: Can you post your code for the invoice page? Where are you rendering the button?

Answer (score 1):

In the component where you use your `SaveConfirmationModal`, you can use state Hooks, like this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
...
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const loadPopup = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };
```

And you need to change the state to false when the modal is dismissed:
`<SaveConfirmationModal show={showModal} onHide={() => setShowModal(false)}`

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function from a prop on button click like below.

```
import { Button, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";
function SaveConfirmationModal(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal {...props} size="lg">
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            do u want to save ?
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <button onClick={props.onYes}>YEs </button>
          <button onClick={props.onNo}>No</button>
        </Modal.Body>
       
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SaveConfirmationModal;
```

Then in your invoice page create a state for showing a modal and pass the props like below.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import SaveConfirmationModal from "components/createinvoice/SaveConfirmationModal";
 
const InvoicePage = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  
  const saveForm = (data) {
   // my save function
  }

  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}> Save </button>
      <SaveConfirmationModal show={showModal} onYes={() => saveForm(data)} onNow={() => setShowModal(false)} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: my save button is as below
     <Button className="btn btn-primary mr-1" type="submit">
                  <i className="mdi mdi-checkbox-marked-circle"></i> Submit
                </Button>

Comment: form submit using form onSubmit. 
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> how i modify this

Comment: But thats not what you have asked in your question.